# Crystal Reports Order By logic switch to asc then desc

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, report

I have a crystal report that contains a location column. I can sort the order by the location column using the Record Sort expert and set as Ascending Order.

However.. the locations now have to not only follow alphabetical order they will have to loop back to highest number when the first or second letters change.

For example:

Locations: AA1, AA2, AA3, BA1, BA2, BA3

To appear in order as

AA1

AA2

AA3

BA3

BA2

BA1

Is that possible? Would I need to use multiple case statements? I would be grateful for any help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

1. Create formulas that returns calculated values.
2. Create groups by these formulas.
3. Let the groups sort the data instead of using "record sort expert".

So, the final trick is the formulas, but it depends on the business rules, wich I don't know exactly.

For example, let's assume that location code has a fixed length of 3 and it is always in the form [A-B][A][0-9]. Furthermore, let's assume A implies in lexicographic ascending order, while B implies in descending order.

In this scenario, I would create two formulas. Let's call them {@FormulaA} and {@FormulaB}.

```
{@FormulaA}: if Left({Table.Location}, 1) = "A" then {Table.Location} else "ZZ"

{@FormulaB}: if Left({Table.Location}, 1) = "B" then {Table.Location} else "ZZ"
```

Then I would create a group by {@FormulaA} followed by a group by {@FormulaB}. Then I would set the group by {@FormulaB} to sort in descending order.